# Outlook add-in Manifest can open taskapane on desktop but can't open taskpane on Outlook for the Web

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently developing an outlook add-in for my company. I have designed a manifest and tested it mostly on desktop, but web tests were made. Currently I cannot open taskpane one the outlook web anymore and no error, debug or other log file is avaliable. Below is an example manifest, it load normally when sideloaded to Outlook Desktop and can open taskpane but on outlook web it loads, becames avaliable on app list but can't open taskpane, no error is given. I tried loading it via office-addin-debugging and adding it manually via https://aka.ms/olksideload both with the same result.

No relevant console information is printed on browser.

Does anyone know the problem or a workaround? or a way for debugging it?

here is the add-in on desktop

[image: screenshot of the taskpane with the example webpage loaded on outlook desktop]

here is the same add-in on web

[image: screenchot depicting outlook web add-in tray with the example add-in loaded]

Here is a reproducible example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>666540ce-167f-11ee-be56-0242ac120666</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="An Outlook add-in template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://script-lab.azureedge.net/assets/images/icon-64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://script-lab.azureedge.net/assets/images/icon-128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
                <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
            <TabletSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
                <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
            </TabletSettings>
            <PhoneSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
            </PhoneSettings>
        </Form>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
            </DesktopSettings>
            <TabletSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
            </TabletSettings>
            <PhoneSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
            </PhoneSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="ReadOrEdit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1"> -->
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.4">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="File.Tab2">
              <Group id="msgComposeGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="composeButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    <!-- Enables your add-in to activate without the Reading Pane enabled or a message selected. -->
                    <!-- <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext> -->
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>

          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="File.Tab">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                    <!-- Enables your add-in to activate without the Reading Pane enabled or a message selected. -->
                    <!-- <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext> -->
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://script-lab.azureedge.net/assets/images/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://script-lab.azureedge.net/assets/images/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://script-lab.azureedge.net/assets/images/icon-64.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Open Taskpane"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Open a taskpane to show a webpage."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

office-addin-manifest validate output

```
Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:
  - Outlook 2013 or later on Windows
  - Outlook 2016 or later on Windows
  - Outlook 2019 or later on Windows
  - Outlook 2013 or later on Mac
  - Outlook 2016 or later on Mac
  - Outlook 2019 or later on Mac
  - Outlook on the web
  - Outlook on Windows (Microsoft 365)
  - Outlook on Mac (Microsoft 365)
Important: This analysis is based on the requirements specified in your manifest and does not account for any runtime JavaScript calls within your add-in. For information about which API sets and features are supported on each platform, see Office Add-in host and platform availability. (https://docs.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability).

*This does not include mobile apps. You can opt-in to support mobile apps when you submit your add-in.

The manifest is valid.
```

Comment: Can you access the `Taskpane.Url` in the web browser? Is it accessible?

Comment: yes I can. I choose the simplest webpage I could find on google :v

Comment: You need to point to your files, not google or any external URLs.

Comment: this was just for the sake of giving a minimal example for this question that others could reproduce. poiting to my local files also does not work.

Comment: So, you can't reach your add-in files from the web browser?

Comment: If I use the localhost url on my browser I can reach the file. The add-in works fine on desktop as I stated on the question. It only doesn't work on outlook web.

Comment: I'd suggest testing a newly created add-in with a task pane to isolate the problem. Just try to scaffold a new one and run it. Do you get the same problem without changing anything in the manifest?

Comment: Glad that my post helped with an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new add-in as suggested and compared with mine. I have done the following things and the problem was solved:

- copied the new generated commands html and ts file to my project.
- updated office-addin-debugging to the new major version.

I have done some other alterations but rollbacking any but those two seem to make the taskpane still be able to be opened, what makes me think those are the problem solvers.

In more detailes the code that seems to have solved the issue is the following line on the end of the Commands script that was missing on my old generated file (I have not changed the commands script since it's generation a year or so ago):

```js
// Register the function with Office.
Office.actions.associate('action', action);
```

If there is anything I'm missing please just comment and will edit.

If you are having similar problems and these was not sufficient please comment and I will try to troubleshoot further.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook on the web, add-ins that implement the `<SupportsNoItemContext>` manifest element don't activate when the Reading Pane is hidden or when a message isn't selected. This is because add-in commands in Outlook on the web don't appear on the ribbon. To activate an add-in from the Message Read surface, you must first select a message, then select the add-in command from the message action bar.

Also I have noticed the following line of markup commented in the manifest file:

```
<!-- <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1"> -->
```

You need to use it. Note, a manifest can implement multiple versions of the `VersionOverrides` element which support different versions of the `VersionOverrides` schema. This can be done to optionally support new features in a newer schema while still supporting older clients that do not support the new features.

To implement both the `VersionOverrides v1.0` and `v1.1` schema, the manifest would look similar to the following example.

```
<OfficeApp ... xsi:type="MailApp">
...
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Description resid="residDescription" />
    <Requirements>
      <!-- add information on requirements -->
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <!-- add information on form factors -->
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <!-- add information on resources -->
    </Resources>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <!-- add information on requirements -->
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <!-- add information on form factors -->
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <!-- add information on resources -->
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>  
  </VersionOverrides>
...
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: I was basing myself of docusign's manifest and they dont use this versionOverrides  v1.1 and still can open on web. I commented it as to have the minimal representation possible as it is easier to troubleshoot. I will try this but would be nice to be able to understand what exactly is the problem as I can provide a instance that does not implement this versionOverrides v1.1 and still works

Comment: Implemented versionOverrides v1.1. As of now I'm not even able to see the button on the add-in tray anymore, reverting back to previous file and changing the version up doesn't seem to resolve the problem. The app is gone.

Comment: Is any item selected when you try to open a task pane?

Comment: In the end it's not needed. Microsoft changed the way they handle the action function export and didn't disclosed anywhere I tried looking... Thanks a lot for your cooperation.

Comment: Correct. But things may not be working otherwise. Just wanted to check the basic scenario works correctly and it is not related to an absent item (not-selected).